# RequestContext como null

Tags: java, primefaces

Estou tentando atualizar um componente na tela pelo `RequestContext` do `primefaces`. Porém há 2 situações onde a primeira é eu clicar em um link e a página dar o seu refresh. A 2ª situação é onde eu tenho um agendador no sistema que chama um método frequentemente, no final deste método eu peço pra se atualizar o componente, aí que está o problema pois o RequestContext chega como null e não tenho sucesso, alguém sabe como posso resolver ?

```
RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.update("listaEncomendas:viewFull:cadastroEdicaoForm:atualizacao");
```

Comment: Você está executando esse método no seu agendador?

Comment: Se seu agendador tiver a função de atualizar um componente jsf você pode cogitar utilizar uma ajax poll que faz atualizações programadas além de ter um fácil controle de inicio e fim da execução https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml

Comment: @ℛɑƒæĿ o agendador tem um método que chama meu método em questão.

Comment: Seu RequestContext não estará disponível pois seu agendador não é um Managed Bean.

Comment: Obrigado, o `poll` funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu `RequestContext` não estará disponível pois seu agendador não é um ManagedBean.

E se você utilizasse o Ajax Poll do Primefaces:

```
<h:form>
    <p:poll interval="3" listener="#{seuBean.funcao()}" update="id_elemento_atualizar" />
</h:form>
```

No exemplo a poll será executada automaticamente quando entrar na página a cada

- Uma nova execução será feita a cada 3 segundos (interval)
- A propriedade autoStart por padrão é true (executada automaticamente quando entrar na página)
- Até você executar um comando javascript para parar a poll ela continuará em execução
- Seu poll deve estar dentro de um form

Comment: Show, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Fico feliz de ter ajudado... Abraço!